# How to set different colors for Top and Bottom in React Native SafeAreaView component?

Tags: react-native

The following approach seems like a good idea for changing the colors of safe areas. However, since I use `TabNavigator` and `StackNavigator`, I have difficulty implementing this approach. The bottom and top colors of each screen are different. So I need to create a dynamic structure. How can it be done?

```js
    import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
    
    function App(){
      return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "yellow", justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }} >
                <Text>This is top text.</Text>
                <Text>This is bottom text.</Text>
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

[image]

**Navigation structure in my current app**

```js
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    
    import { TabBar } from "../components";
    
    import A from "../screens/A";
    import B from "../screens/B";
    import Detail from "../screens/Detail";
    
    function TabScreens() {
    
        const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
        return (
            <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
                <Tab.Screen name="a" component={A} />
                <Tab.Screen name="b" component={B} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        );
    }
    
    function StackScreens() {
    
        const Stack = createStackNavigator();
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"tabScreens"} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false }}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="tabScreens" component={TabScreens} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="detail" component={Detail} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
    
    function App() {
        return <StackScreens />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a reusable CustomScreen.js**

```js
    export default function CustomScreen({
      topColor,
      bottomColor,
      backgroundColor,
      style = { justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" },
      children,
    }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: topColor }} />

          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: bottomColor }}>
            <View style={[{ flex: 1, backgroundColor }, style]}>
             {children}
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

**import it where needed**

```js
    function OtherScreens() {
      return (
        <CustomScreen topColor="red" bottomColor="blue" backgroundColor="yellow">
          <Text>This is top text.</Text>
          <Text>This is bottom text.</Text>
        </CustomScreen>
      );
    }
```

Comment: This method does not work properly because it does not include Tab.Navigator. That's why I opened the issue. Since Tab.Navigator is used frequently, I thought maybe there was a practical way.

Answer (score 0):

you could use background linear on the SafeAreaView.
(not sure the support for it in reactNative tho)

```
  background: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    topColor 0%,
    topColor 50%,
    bottomColor 50%,
    bottomColor 100%
  );
```

edit: looks like you need a reactnativey workaround package to do it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient